# create view for from 1 table and 2 views and become 1 row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, view

Halo guys, i'm a newbie and i need the solution for my homework.

for the first sorry if my English is not good.

1. so i have 2 tables, 1 table is employees data (name of table is emp) and another one is
   time in and time out of the employees (name of table is att_punches), with flag 0 for time in and
   flag 1 for time out.
2. i have made two views from att_punches to separate time_in and time_out, there are vw_in and vw_out.

   - table emp
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKzTa.png)
   - vw_in
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DsKF.png)
   - vw_out [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxRqz.png)

there are some cases, employees forget to punch when they come or when they go home, and if they don't come then of course they won't punch.

i need a view that can show the date and who not punch when they come or go home and not punch for the employee that not come.

i have joined the table with 2 views, but only 1 date, query like this

```
SELECT a.emp_pin, a.emp_name, 
       CASE WHEN b.date IS NULL THEN c.date ELSE b.date END AS DATE, 
       b.time_in, c.time_out
FROM   emp a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT emp_pin, emp_name, DATE, time_in 
                   FROM vw_in WHERE DATE = '2020-02-05') b
             ON a.emp_pin = b.emp_pin
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT emp_pin, emp_name, DATE, time_out  
                  FROM vw_out WHERE DATE = '2020-02-05') c
             ON a.emp_pin = c.emp_pin;
```

the result like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJwuo.png)

**all that i want is make all data in one view, so when i need to see who employees not punch when come or back and who not come for today, just do** `select * from [view_name] where date between [start_date] and [until_date]`

I've prepared for table & data for table `emp` & `att_punches` [fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sRC7iaLZa6YkWtQ3ibthjK/0)

thank you so much.

Comment: Was the creation of views a specific requirement of the assignment?

Comment: yes, that is the specific requirement

Comment: That's a shame, because queries against views in MySQL are fantastically inefficient

Comment: I think so, but that's the requirement. could you show me the efficient way?